# Screen turns to white after returning from camera intent in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, camera, imageview

I am running through a weird situation. Please help me out.

I am developing an application in which user has to capture two images from camera to register i.e. User Photo and Address Photo.

When I try to capture image from back side camera. I can do that successfully. But when I use front camera of **mobile device screen turns to white after capturing second image**.

PS : Registration Form is in fragment.

I have searched for it but couldn't find any solution for it. Help me to solve it out.

[image]

**Source Code :**

```
private void captureImage(int ImageCode) {

    Context context = getActivity();
    PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
    if (packageManager.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA) == false
            && packageManager
                    .hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_ANY) == false) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.camera_is_not_available,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (takePictureIntent
            .resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Error occurred while creating the File
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.error_connecting_camera,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {

            if (ImageCode == CAPTURE_MEMBER_PHOTO_REQUEST_CODE) {
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                        Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent,
                        CAPTURE_MEMBER_PHOTO_REQUEST_CODE);

                img_reg_member_photo.setImageBitmap(null);
                mMemberPhotoPath = null;
                memberImageflag = false;
            }
            if (ImageCode == CAPTURE_ADDRESS_PHOTO_REQUEST_CODE) {
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                        Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent,
                        CAPTURE_ADDRESS_PHOTO_REQUEST_CODE);

                img_reg_address_proof.setImageBitmap(null);
                mAddressPhotoPath = null;
                addressImageflag = false;
            }
        }
    }
}

@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")
            .format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = Environment
            .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(imageFileName, ".jpg", storageDir);

    mPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();

    Log.v("createImageFile", "" + mPhotoPath);
    return image;
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == CAPTURE_MEMBER_PHOTO_REQUEST_CODE
            && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

        File imgFile = new File(mPhotoPath);
        if (imgFile.exists()) {

            mMemberPhotoPath = mPhotoPath;
            BitmapFactory.Options bitmap_options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            bitmap_options.inSampleSize = 4;
            bitmap_options.outHeight = 200;
            bitmap_options.outWidth = 200;

            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(
                    imgFile.getAbsolutePath(), bitmap_options);
            img_reg_member_photo.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

            if (img_reg_member_photo.getDrawable() == null) {
                Log.e("MEMBER IMAGE VIEW", "NULL MEMBER IMAGE");
                memberImageflag = false;
            } else {
                Log.e("MEMBER IMAGE VIEW", "MEMBER IMAGE VIEW UPDATED");
                memberImageflag = true;
            }
        }
    } else if (requestCode == CAPTURE_MEMBER_PHOTO_REQUEST_CODE
            && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.camera_operation_canceled,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        memberImageflag = false;
        img_reg_member_photo.setImageBitmap(null);

        Log.e("MEMBER IMAGE VIEW", "CANCEL EVENT - NULL MEMBER IMAGE"
                + img_reg_member_photo.getDrawable());

    }

    if (requestCode == CAPTURE_ADDRESS_PHOTO_REQUEST_CODE
            && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

        File imgFile = new File(mPhotoPath);
        if (imgFile.exists()) {

            mAddressPhotoPath = mPhotoPath;
            BitmapFactory.Options bitmap_options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            bitmap_options.inSampleSize = 4;
            bitmap_options.outHeight = 200;
            bitmap_options.outWidth = 200;

            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(
                    imgFile.getAbsolutePath(), bitmap_options);

            img_reg_address_proof.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

            if (img_reg_address_proof.getDrawable() == null) {
                Log.e("ADDRESS IMAGE VIEW", "NULL ADDRESS IMAGE");
                addressImageflag = false;
            } else {
                Log.e("ADDRESS IMAGE VIEW", "ADDRESS IMAGE VIEW UPDATED");
                addressImageflag = true;
            }
        }
    } else if (requestCode == CAPTURE_ADDRESS_PHOTO_REQUEST_CODE
            && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.camera_operation_canceled,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        addressImageflag = false;
        img_reg_address_proof.setImageBitmap(null);

        Log.e("ADDRESS IMAGE VIEW", "CANCEL EVENT - NULL ADDRESS IMAGE"
                + img_reg_address_proof.getDrawable());

    }
}
```

**XML :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.equesttech.mybyk.slidingfragments.FractionalLinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_label_navigate"
        style="?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="@drawable/box_green"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:text="@string/tap_to_close"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
            android:padding="10dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_label_user_registration"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="@string/register_member"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@color/actionbar"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_member_acc_details"
                style="?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="@string/member_acc_details"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edt_reg_firstname"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/box_edittext"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/first_name"
                android:padding="10dp" >
            </EditText>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edt_reg_lastname"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/box_edittext"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/last_name"
                android:padding="10dp" >
            </EditText>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_gender"
                style="?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="@string/gender"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/radio_grp_gender"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radio_male"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/male" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radio_female"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/female" />
            </RadioGroup>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:visibility="visible" >

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/edt_reg_dob"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/box_edittext"
                        android:clickable="false"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:focusable="false"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                        android:hint="@string/dob"
                        android:inputType="datetime"
                        android:padding="12dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/black" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn_delete_reg_dob"
                        android:layout_width="32dp"
                        android:layout_height="32dp"
                        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/edt_reg_dob"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/delete_item"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:visibility="gone" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_reg_dob"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/box_cyan"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/date"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edt_reg_contactnumber"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/box_edittext"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/contact_number"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:maxLength="10"
                android:padding="10dp" >
            </EditText>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_member_documents"
                style="?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="@string/member_documents"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/view_current_photo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="visible" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_current_photo"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="@string/current_photo"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_select_member_photo"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/box_red"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/capture_image"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_reg_member_photo"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/address_proof"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/view_driving_license"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="visible" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_driving_license"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="@string/address_proof"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_select_driving_license"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/box_red"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/capture_image"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_reg_address_proof"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/address_proof"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="5dp" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_submit"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/box_green"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/submit"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_clear"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/box_cyan"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/clear"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</com.equesttech.mybyk.slidingfragments.FractionalLinearLayout>
```

Comment: POst your Xml .... and also try to set both images to Image view seperatly on Second Photo Capture .....

Answer (score -1):

this is a working code in one of my app it captures image from both front and back cam and is used inside a fragment.I have an image crop feature in extra please avoid it when you use if unnecessary

```
mCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(taken_image==null) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    Uri fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE); // create a file to save the image
                    image_uri = fileUri;
                    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri); // set the image file name
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

                    dialog.cancel();
                    mEdit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

            }
        });


 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, final Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK&&requestCode==1) {

            if(image_uri!=null)
                try {
                   capture=true;

                    performCrop(image_uri);

                } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), e + "\"memory exception occured\"", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    taken_image = null;
                    round_Image = null;
                    upload_image_hd = null;

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), e + "\"exception occured\"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    taken_image = null;
                    round_Image = null;
                    upload_image_hd = null;

                }


        }
 else if (requestCode == 3) {  //after cropping of profilepic
            // get the returned data
            try {
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            // get the cropped bitmap
          Bitmap  thePic = extras.getParcelable("data");
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println(e);
            }


            if(capture){

            ExifInterface exif = null;
            try {
                exif = new ExifInterface(image_uri.getPath());
               //Since API Level 5
            int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
            //TODO
            upload_image_hd =BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image_uri.getPath());
            switch (orientation) {
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                Rotate90Bitmap(thePic,upload_image_hd, 90);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                Rotate180Bitmap(thePic,upload_image_hd, 180);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                Rotate270Bitmap(thePic,upload_image_hd, 270);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL:
                RotateBitmap(thePic,upload_image_hd, 0);
                break;
            default:
                RotateBitmap(thePic,upload_image_hd, 0);
                break;
        }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }  
            catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), e + "\"memory exception occured\"", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                taken_image = null;
                round_Image = null;
                upload_image_hd = null;

            } catch (Exception e) {

                taken_image = null;
                round_Image = null;
                upload_image_hd = null;

            }  
            }

    }



/**
     * this function does the crop operation.
     */
    private void performCrop(Uri picUri) {
        // take care of exceptions
        try {
            // call the standard crop action intent (the user device may not
            // support it)
            Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");           
            // indicate image type and Uri
            cropIntent.setDataAndType(picUri, "image/*");
            // set crop properties
            cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
            // indicate aspect of desired crop
            cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 2);
            cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
            // indicate output X and Y
            cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 256);
            cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 256);
            // retrieve data on return
            cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
            // start the activity - we handle returning in onActivityResult
            startActivityForResult(cropIntent, 3);
        }
        // respond to users whose devices do not support the crop action
        catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
            Toast toast = Toast
                    .makeText(getActivity(), "This device doesn't support the crop action!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
        }



/*
/
 public Bitmap RotateBitmap(Bitmap crop,Bitmap source, float angle) {
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(angle);

        round_Image = Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(), matrix, true);
        // get the base 64 string
        imgString = Base64.encodeToString(getBytesFromBitmap(round_Image),Base64.NO_WRAP);
        Bitmap cropimg=Bitmap.createBitmap(crop, 0, 0, crop.getWidth(), crop.getHeight(), matrix, true);
        imgcroppedString=Base64.encodeToString(getBytesFromBitmap(cropimg),Base64.NO_WRAP);
        uploadProfilePicture_bytes();
        return Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(), matrix, true);
    }

    public Bitmap Rotate90Bitmap(Bitmap crop,Bitmap source, float angle) {
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(angle);

        round_Image = Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(), matrix, true);
        Bitmap cropimg=Bitmap.createBitmap(crop, 0, 0, crop.getWidth(), crop.getHeight(), matrix, true);
        imgcroppedString=Base64.encodeToString(getBytesFromBitmap(cropimg),Base64.NO_WRAP);
        // get the base 64 string
        imgString = Base64.encodeToString(getBytesFromBitmap(round_Image),Base64.NO_WRAP);
        uploadProfilePicture_bytes();
        return Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(), matrix, true);
    }

    public Bitmap Rotate180Bitmap(Bitmap crop,Bitmap source, float angle) {
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(angle);

        round_Image = Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(), matrix, true);
        Bitmap cropimg=Bitmap.createBitmap(crop, 0, 0, crop.getWidth(), crop.getHeight(), matrix, true);
        imgcroppedString= Base64.encodeToString(getBytesFromBitmap(cropimg),Base64.NO_WRAP);
        // get the base 64 string
        imgString = Base64.encodeToString(getBytesFromBitmap(round_Image),Base64.NO_WRAP);

        uploadProfilePicture_bytes();
        return Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(), matrix, true);
    }

    public Bitmap Rotate270Bitmap(Bitmap crop,Bitmap source, float angle) {
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(angle);

        round_Image = Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(), matrix, true);
        // get the base 64 string
        imgString = Base64.encodeToString(getBytesFromBitmap(round_Image),Base64.NO_WRAP);

        Bitmap cropimg=Bitmap.createBitmap(crop, 0, 0, crop.getWidth(), crop.getHeight(), matrix, true);
        imgcroppedString= Base64.encodeToString(getBytesFromBitmap(cropimg),Base64.NO_WRAP);

        uploadProfilePicture_bytes();
        return Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(), matrix, true);
    }
```